# Vortex equation on Riemann surface and a similar equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemann-surfaces, kahler-manifolds, gauge-theory

Let's take a Riemann surface $(X,\omega)$ and a holomorphic line bundle $L$ on it with a hermitian metric $h$ on $L$. $g$ be a real valued smooth function on $X$ and we consider the following two sets of equations on $X$ for sections $\phi,\psi$ and connections $A,B$ compatible with $h$ on $L$.

\begin{equation}
\bar\partial\phi=0, F_A=\frac{i}{4}(|\phi|^2-a)\omega, a>>0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\bar\partial\psi=0, F_B=\frac{i}{4}(e^g|\psi|^2-b)\omega, b>>0
\end{equation}

The first on is the well known Vortex equations and the second one is similar to it and both can be solved (upto gauge) using similar technique, e.g., using Kadzan-Warner's equation. My question is: can we get solutions of the second set of equations from the first one, maybe with $a=b,$ or with some sort of similar assumption, at least up to gauge?